# Optimizar Vista e Índice POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la siguiente vista

```
CREATE  materialized view vista_listado_products_global_1_product_id as
SELECT t3.name,
       t3.display_type,
       t2.value,
       t1.product_global_id,
       pg.product_id,
       t4.url
FROM products_global_variants t1
         JOIN variants t2 ON t1.variant_id = t2.variant_id
         JOIN dimensions t3 ON t2.dimension_id = t3.dimension_id
         JOIN files_global t4 ON t4.product_global_id = t1.product_global_id
         JOIN products_global pg on t1.product_global_id = pg.product_global_id ;
```

Y el siguiente índice

```
create  index 
index_vista_listado_products_global_1_product_id
on vista_listado_products_global_1_product_id (
    name, display_type, value, 
    product_global_id, product_id, url
);
```

Los datos que me retornan son las variantes que un producto principal tiene asociado es decir

1. Tengo unos zapatos Y sus variantes son Blanco y la talla , así como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo funciona correctamente. pero el tiempo de respuesta es algo critico. ya que se demora un poco en retornar los resultados. aunque al hacer este proceso mejoro mucho pero la idea es mejorarlo mas.

EXPLAIN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo optimizar la vista? , ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si haces un EXPLAIN de esa consulta, qué te dice? Qué versión de PGSQL usas? Cada cuánto refrescas la vista materializada? Puede haber bloqueos entre la actualización y la lectura...

Comment: @Alfabravo acabe de poner el resultado del explain, la version que uso de postgres es PostgreSQL 9.6.17 . la vista materializada se refresca cada que se hace peticion desde el sitio web para cargar la informacion. de referencia te puedes guiar por esta URL https://kieroapi.org/detalle/80748206 y lo que te carga al lado derecho las imagenes en miniatura

Comment: Esta vista es la que hace el trabajo. @Alfabravo

Comment: O sea que, cada vez que cargo la camisa en el sitio, refresca la vista??? Es que el EXPLAIN está diciendo que, por ejemplo, haces un montón de sequential scans (porque cargas todo) y ordenamientos (todos esos sort). Es como si las tablas de origen no estuvieran bien indexadas por los campos que haces el join. E igual, el REFRESH de la vista debería ser cuando se modifiquen los datos, cada 3 minutos, cada N tiempo para que valga la pena que sea materializada

Comment: Comprendo. podrías regalarme algún ejemplo de como hacerlo? @Alfabravo